How Do I Stop Music.app from Opening And Playing Whenever A New Audio Device is Plugged In?
I have a USB hub on my desk which is connected to a set of speakers. Whenever I plug my Macbook into the hub, Music.app opens and starts playing the alphabetically first album in my library.
This is really annoying. How can I prevent this from happening? I can't find any settings in System Settings or Music.app that are obviously related to this.
